# Application Upgrade to newer version and remove old version support

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an android application which runs android version 2.3 or above . Now I am planing to upgrade to newer version and use material design. Also update minimum support version to 4.0.3

My question is that if i update the minimum support version to 4.0.3 then what happens to users who use old version? Can they still download my old version app or Will the app be invisible for old version mobile ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

> Will the app be invisible for old version mobile

Android 2.x users can use old application, but they can't upgrade it.

[You can try create multiple apk to old and new androids](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html)

However, I recommend completely abandon support for older versions. Support takes a lot of effort, and users with each passing day it becomes less.

[image]

[dashboard from developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform)

Comment: The answer is right but it would be good if it was worded better. Maybe add some references?

Comment: So where's the answer for the question *what happens to users who use the old version?*

Comment: @reVerse nothing. They will cannot upgrade app.

Comment: @KirillShalnov That's kind of missing in your answer isn't it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Every user running an Android-Version below 4.0.3 will still be eligible to download your old version (at least as long as you're not deactivating the old one).

See the following Screenshot of the Developer-Console - it basically explains everything:

[image: screenshot of developer console with multiple apks]